# erro ao dar o comando rake db:create em rails verão 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bem, estou começando no Ruby on rails, gostaria de entender o seguinte erro ao gerar o comando

```
rake db:create
```

para que eu possa solucioná-lo.

```
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:48:in `autodetect'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/uglifier-2.7.2/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/home/jefferson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@catalo/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/home/jefferson/Documentos/Ruby_project/catalo/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/home/jefferson/Documentos/Ruby_project/catalo/Rakefile:4:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo Gemfile, você também adicionar a gem:

> gem 'therubyracer'

Depois é só dar um bundle install e tentar de novo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta digitar esses comandos no terminal

```
gem install execjs
sudo aptitude install nodejs -y
sudo apt-get install g++ -y
gem install therubyracer
```